# virt-install hangs and won't die. How to stop safely?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kill, kill-process, virt-install, freeze

I am having a problem where virt-install gets stuck in the very early stages and cant be killed (after saying "starting installation", but before the VM is visible in virt-manager).

Ctrl-C does not work to cancel virt-install, and `systemctl restart libvirtd` just hangs. I have to hard restart the machine. Even `kill $libvirtPID` just hangs. If I restart, restart hangs with a message of `kvm: exiting hardware virtualization`, and I have to hard restart.

For the moment, I am not asking for help with the *cause* of the hang, but rather I want to know whether there is a better/safer way to cancel a frozen virt-install.

Comment: If it's hung that badly, then there won't be any "cancel a frozen virt-install". You will have to fix the underlying cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience if something hangs *that* hard that plain `kill` is ignored, there isn't any friendly way to exit the hung applications. Maybe `kill -9` will help, but if host reboot also hangs with messages about kvm it could very well be a kernel bug, in which case there's likely not much you can do to recover nicely.